# Best way to not update empty posts

Tags: php, codeigniter

- Hello,

  Im using codeigniter, and the page in case just update infos about
  an user. If the user go to the page and edit values and that posts
  come as "" or empty (samething) then no update it let the query pass
  it, i got a logic but its a bit ugly and ill take alot of time.

  ```
     $nome = "'nome' =>" . $this->input->post('nome') . "'";
     $sobrenome = "'sobrenome' =>" . $this->input->post('sobrenome') . "'";

     if($nome != ""){

         $nome = "'nome' =>" . $this->input->post('nome') . "'";

         }else{

         $nome = "";
     }
     if($sobrenome != ""){
          $sobrenome = "'sobrenome' =>" . $this->input->post('sobrenome') . "'";
     }else{

         $sobrenome = "";
     } $data = array($nome, $sobrenome);
  ```

The problem is, i got alot of fields :(

If anyone know a smart way or a better way, please i want know

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The best way to do it..mines take alot of time.

Comment: @user1533106 what does $this->input->post return? does it return an array or object?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan its return value of input, but using this function prevents any malicious script, because the layer of protection built in codeigniter

Comment: @user1533106 - simple question, is it an array type or object type. anyway take a look at [array fliter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array and use ternary operators

```
$data = array(
         'nome' => strlen($this->input->post('nome'))>0 ? $this->input->post('nome') : NULL,
         'sobrenome' => strlen($this->input->post('sobrenome'))>0 ? $this->input->post('sobrenome') : NULL,
        );
```

If you want to remove the `NULL` values from the array then add `$data = array_filter($data);`

You don't need to define individual variables for `$nome` and `$sobrenome`.  You can get those values with `$data['nome']` and `$data['sobrenome']`.

Comment: Ok, but when ill use $this->db->update($data) it ill replace NULL values to any value in db.

Comment: Yeah, the values that are not entered should be NULL.  How do you want them to de stored?

Comment: If they come as null then no run into query of update.

Comment: Like your name, if you clean post name BUT let address correctly it just update address post and leave name because its empty

Comment: Change the `NULL` into something else if you want it to be something else.  I don't know what you mean, if someone doesn't enter anything into an input it is `NULL` - how do you want it to be stored?

Comment: Then i dont want store it, just pass in query... as it doenst exists example : update "nome" value "teste" ok your name is now teste, if you come into your edit page and delete name test but update any other info, just dont run query to update name but run the others one